# The stream or file "/path/to/project/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied on Fedora 26

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, fpm, fedora-26

I was trying to setup my development workstation on Fedora 26.
So I install Nginx, php-fpm and MySQL 5.7. I also change the user who execute php on `/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf`

I put my fresh laravel installation on `/var/www/html/` and change the owner of the `/var/www/html` to the one who run php-fpm.

I set up my nginx configuration

```
server {
    server_name laravel5.dev;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/laravel5.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/laravel5.error.log;
    root /var/www/html/laravel5/public;

    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri /index.php =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

So. The homepage is running correctly. And I install the basic authentication from laravel. And when I got go into the `/login` page. I got some error that the laravel.log is `permission denied`. I am pretty sure that I set its permission to 777 and the owner of the directory is the owner of the php-fpm.

Is there something that I missed? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `I am pretty sure` is not enough :-) Check - did you, or didn't you?  [The installation docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5) describe exactly what steps to do permissions-wise.

Comment: yes I already set `bootstrap/cache` and `storage` to 777

Comment: Setting permissions on `storage` is not what the docs say you need to do.  They say: `Directories within the storage and the bootstrap/cache directories should be writable by your web server`.  Directories *within*, which means eg `storage/logs/`.